# android: how do i save and load and int value using internal storage

Tags: android, save, int, storage, internal

i'm looking for a way to save and load data in android, i'm using eclipse & 
I DO NOT want to use SharedPreferences at all, so please do not suggest that

save() which i think i've figured out and i have done like this:

```
int blankval = 1;
int targetval = 0;
FileOutputStream fou = openFileOutput("data.gds", MODE_PRIVATE);
fou.write(blankval);
fou.write(targetval);
fou.close();
```

while load() i have no idea how to do, i've tried many things and all make the app crash upon executing

i want to load each val back into the two ints (blankval & targetval) so that if i do:

```
blankval = 5;
targetval = 7;
load();
```

load will then set their values back to 0 & 1

Comment: SharedPreferences is safe and efficient, just wondering why not use it? If there is a reason not to use it it might help determine the best way to achieve what you want.

Comment: You do realise that `SharedPreferences` simply use an XML file saved to internal storage don't you? Why re-invent the wheel?

Comment: all i really wanted is to use read() to get the int value, i dislike SharedPreferences because i want to use my own file format like .gds

Comment: OK, first point - the `write(int)` method of `FileOutputStream` writes a single byte (8-bit signed integer) whereas a default Java int is a 32-bit signed integer. As long as you're aware of that and can compensate, i.e., you never need to save any values less than -128 or more than 128 then that's fine. Second point you say you've tried "many things" but you haven't shown us any of them so we're left to guess at what you've done. Third point - you say the app crashes but you haven't posted the logcat to show the stacktrace of when it crashes.

Answer (score 0):

SharedPreferences will be a good choice, however if you wanna avoid that then why not go for **SQLite Database** provided by Android.

Comment: LOL - if the OP doesn't want to use SharedPreferences then a SQLite DB has really got to be overkill.

Comment: @Squonk Yes but using FileSystem to store some int values, i can't imagine coding like that :)

Answer (score 0):

I have to recommend you use SharedPreferences :) , but any way...

If you need to reed the value you just write, you should use **openFileInput**:

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileInput(java.lang.String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileInput%28java.lang.String%29)

example:

```
FileInputStream in = openFileInput("data.gds");
InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(in);
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
String line;
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    //Convert each line to your int
    int value = Integer.parseInt(line); 
}
```

of course , for this to work, you need write your ints (**one int per line**) to the file with OutputStreamWriter:

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html

example of write an int line by line:

```
  writer = new OutputStreamWriter(fou);
  int blankval = 1;
  writer.write(String.valueOf(blankval)+"\n");
  int targetval = 0;
  writer.write(String.valueOf(targetval)+"\n");
  writer.close();
```

or something like that...

Comment: how would i go about writing my ints?